# HTypeError: unhashable type: 'collections.OrderedDict' issue in amazon-dax-client==2.0.0

Tags: amazon-dynamodb-dax

I am facing TypeError: unhashable type: 'collections.OrderedDict' while getting data from DAX client.

Version - amazon-dax-client==2.0.0 , python 3.8.7

please find this stacktrace:
GetItemIssue, batch_keys:{'beauty_mapping_details': {'Keys': [{'id': '123'}, {'id': '345'}, {'id': '556'}, {'id': '777'}, {'id': '111'}]}} tableName:beauty_mapping_details
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ubuntu/pds_script/sharedutils/dynamodbutils.py", line 81, in batch_get_item
response = self.dynamo_client.batch_get_item(RequestItems=batch_keys,
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in **call**
response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args, **params)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amazondax/AmazonDaxClient.py", line 209, in batch_get_item
return self._read_request('batch_get_item', **kwargs)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amazondax/AmazonDaxClient.py", line 255, in _read_request
return self._retryable_request(rclient, op_name, **kwargs)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amazondax/AmazonDaxClient.py", line 274, in _retryable_request
raise e
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amazondax/AmazonDaxClient.py", line 267, in _retryable_request
response = self._do_request(action, op_name, **kwargs)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amazondax/AmazonDaxClient.py", line 306, in _do_request
response = action(**api_params)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amazondax/DaxClient.py", line 86, in batch_get_item
result = self._resolve_attribute_values(result, tube)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amazondax/DaxClient.py", line 465, in _resolve_attribute_values
self._resolve_item_attribute_values(item, tube)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amazondax/DaxClient.py", line 479, in _resolve_item_attribute_values
AttributeValueDecoder.deanonymize_attribute_values(item, attr_names)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amazondax/AttributeValueDecoder.py", line 32, in deanonymize_attribute_values
values = dict(zip(attr_names, attr_values))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'collections.OrderedDict'

I have tried to reproduce it on testing but failed to do that. But the same has been occurred on prod.
Please help me to resolve this issue. Athough, we have same dependency and all but issue is with prod env not with testing one.